# How I can iterate over an array and pass items to a method also all methods should run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, synchronization, httprequest

I want to call a request method that gets the body of itself as an array that is also one item of another array. so I should iterate over this parent array and pass its items to request method for a new request to server.
I have used `bodies.forEach` but this make the calls `async` and I should also do something after every response and need `sync` calls. What is the best way to do this?

```js
bodies = [ [['name', 'Saeid'], ['age','23']],
           [['name', 'Saeid'], ['age', 23 ], ['city', 'Tehran']]
          ]
bodies.forEach(function(body){
  request(body, function(res){
    //do something with this response and if meet oure desired condition continue...
    )};
 });
```

Comment: that is not valid javascript, is it?

Comment: This is NodeJS as a server side Javascript

Comment: Sorry its coffeescript, let edit it

Comment: that explains the `->` anyway :p

Comment: Yep `->` is equal to `{ }` in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.slice()`, `Array.prototype.shift()` to return results in sequential order corresponding to input array

```
bodies = [ [['name', 'Saeid'], ['age','23']],
           [['name', 'Saeid'], ['age', 23 ], ['city', 'Tehran']]
          ];

var copy = bodies.slice(0);
var results = [];

function queue(arr) { 
  let curr = arr.shift();
  request(curr, (res) => {
    // do stuff with `res`
    // results.push(res);
    if (arr.length /* && if meet oure desired condition continue... */) {
      queue(arr)
    }
  })
}

queue(copy);
```

Comment: Its don't know how to implement it, I just find that this solution is recursive and use promises :)

Comment: @SAlidadi _"Its don't know how to implement it"_ Have you tried pattern at Answer? _"I just find that this solution is recursive and use promises :)"_ Yes, approach uses recursion and `Promise`; though `Promise` portion can be removed and should return same result

Comment: @SAlidadi See updated post; removed `Promise` portions. You can include `&&` at `if` condition to either continue to next item within array or stop recursive call to function

Comment: Does request reach server using `js` at Question? See updated post, removed `return` in `queue` function