# Why this forms attachment with stream reader doesn't work truly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read an image and attach it to request body as follow:

```js
// Sending files to server by adding and posting theme

// 1. loop through an array of file path pair ['file', 'path' ]

// 2. pass result to request function an post it
```

some codes as follow:

```js
forms = [];
len = 3;
while (len > 0){
  forms.push({ 'fileName': fs.createReadStream (path) })
  len--
  }
async.each(forms, function(form) {
  request.post( { url : url, formData: form }, function(err, response) {
               console.log(response.body)
  });
});
```

Just one request made and one form element also.

Comment: You're missing braces around the `while` body; this shouldn't work at all

Comment: What is purpose of using `while` loop? Not certain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to post a `ReadableStream` from client to server?

Comment: I fixed the braces :)

Comment: @guest271314 `while` makes an form object that contains a file stream and push it to forms array

Comment: @guest271314 Yep trying to send an image 3 times to a server from client

Comment: @SAlidadi Are you trying to send the same image three times to server?

Comment: Yes I try to send jus one file

Comment: @guest271314 I got the file just one time outside of loop but the result was  same

Comment: @guest271314 now I set just file in loop but there is more fields that all are strings

Comment: What do you mean by _"the result was same"_?

Comment: @guest271314 I mean just one request and one form data

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
forms.forEach(form => 
  request.post( { url : url, formData: form }
  , (err, response) => console.log(response.body))
);
```

Comment: I need to be `sync` requests in series

Comment: @SAlidadi  _"I need to be sync requests in series"_  You can use same approach demonstrated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670458/how-i-can-iterate-over-an-array-and-pass-items-to-a-method-also-all-methods-shou ; loops, generally, do not wait for current asynchronous function to complete process before proceeding to next item in iterable

Comment: The problem is form data creation

Comment: @SAlidadi _"The problem is form data creation"_ What do you mean?

Comment: Is server expecting `ReadableStream`?